# How can I get all the checkins and location status produced by my friends ordered by updated time desc

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am not getting all results which I can see on my timeline in Checkins api and location_post fql. The results returned are very old and can't be sorted.

I have following permission

user_checkin
user_location

friend_checkin
friend_location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of all checkins from your friends that have happened in the last 6 months (2678400 seconds in a month).

> SELECT author_uid, tagged_uids, target_id, coords, timestamp FROM
>   checkin WHERE author_uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 =
>   me()) and timestamp > (now() - (2678400*6))